# Background-attachment не работает на некоторых смартфонах и планшетах, это лечится?

Tags: html, javascript, css

День добрый! Дело в том что заметил прискорбную вещь - на некоторых смартфонах и планшетах, это свойство просто игнорируется - так же плохо работает background-size - к слову все устройства на которых плохо работает - на андроиде, кто нибудь пробовал это лечить??

Comment: еще ерунда с бэкграундом на одном планшете он поверх всего вылезает вот css 
 
    html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font:13px Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Grande; color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(./img/bg.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;

    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данное свойство в режиме fixed не поддерживается мобильными браузерами почти всеми.  Вот спсиок кто поддерживает и кто частично: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-attachment

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/8xq6d045/

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

html {
  background: url(http://img-7.photosight.ru/c81/5868139_thumb.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

или так

http://jsfiddle.net/47eq0ne8/

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background-image: url(http://img-7.photosight.ru/c81/5868139_thumb.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: в 1м варианте у меня бэкграунд пропал после  no-repeat center center fixed; этого - а вот второй помог теперь на смартфоне фикированный стоит тоже - но тот глюк с отображением на планшете - когда бэкграунд там встает на передний план и закрывает поооооолностью весь сайт собой - думаю попробывать z-index поставить у него

Answer (score 1):

Нужно искать полифиллы на *JavaScript*. А так происходит потому-что при `background-attachment:fixed;` при скролле происходит перерисовка картинки что может снизить производительность сайта на мобильных устройствах.

К счастью есть плагин parallax.js который использует хитрость с абсолютным позиционированием http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

```css
div {
height:100vh;
}
body {
height:10000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png"></div>
```